# Use issubset to compare set values between two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns that are filled with pandas sets. I want to check that all values in one column are a subset of the other column. I thought the code below would work but it seems you cannot apply .issubset() to two series with sets.

Ex:

```
data = [[['one','orange','green'],['one','orange']],[['milk','honey'],['Clarke', 'honey']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column_1','Column_2'])

Are_all_column_2_values_valid = df.loc[:, 'Column_2'].apply(set).issubset(df.loc[:, 'Column_1'])

desired_output = pd.series([True,False])
```

All values in both sets will be strings.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

First ensure you actually have series of sets:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(set))
```

Then use the syntactic sugar `<=` for [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
print(df['Column_2'] <= df['Column_1'])

0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I am trying to apply the set to two columns of a larger pandas dataframe. I tried:

df['Column_1'] = df['Column_1'].apply(lambda x: x.apply(set))

but get an error 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply''

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> [set(v).issubset(i) for v, i in zip(df.Column_2, df.Column_1)]
[True, False]
```

Or as a Series:

```
>>> pd.Series(set(v).issubset(i) for v, i in zip(df.Column_2, df.Column_1))
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```